# An activity getting data from service and transfer the data to the other activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service

I create an gpsservice, a main activity with two buttons and a list activity. I'd like to get the gpsservie data when the gps data is obtained, so I create a gps receiver in the main activity to get the data. When I click the button in the main activity, it turns to the list activity. I'd like to transfer the obtained data to the list activity by using intent() when the button is clicked. the problem is that when I click the button, there is nothing shown in the listview.

the key codes of GPS service :

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            additem(location);
            addgeo(location);
            //String latLongString = "Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "\nLong:" + location.getLongitude();
            Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.geotask.gpsdata");
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lat", (ArrayList<Integer>) lat);
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lon", (ArrayList<Integer>) lon);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", (ArrayList<String>) position);
            //intent.putExtra("data", latLongString);
            sendBroadcast(intent);    }
```

the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public  ArrayList<String> position1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public  ArrayList<Long> time=new ArrayList<Long>();
    public  ArrayList<Integer> lat1= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    public  ArrayList<Integer> lon1= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    private BroadcastReceiver gpsreceiver;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("com.example.geotask.gpsdata");
        gpsreceiver=new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
             ArrayList<String> position1=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
             ArrayList<Integer> lat1=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lat");
            ArrayList<Integer> lon1=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lon");
            }

        };
        this.registerReceiver(gpsreceiver, intentFilter);

        final Button listbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        listbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent =new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, list.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", (ArrayList<String>) position1);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        }
```

the list activity:

```
public class list extends Activity{ 
    static ArrayList<listdetails> details = new ArrayList<listdetails>();
   // private BroadcastReceiver gpsreceiver;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.list); 
        ListView listView; 
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        List<String> ex=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
        customlist Adapter = new customlist(details, this);
        listView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        listdetails Detail = new listdetails();
            for(int i=0;i<ex.size();i++)
            {
                Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Detail.setPlace(ex.get(i));
                Detail.setTime("2012.12.2");
                details.add(Detail);

            }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating your variables in `onReceive()`. This means that the `ArrayList` variables get destroyed once `onReceive()` completes. Your `onReceive()` should look like:

```
        @Override 
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
          position1=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
          lat1=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lat");
         lon1=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lon");
        }
```

This ensures that you are now modifying the **global** ArrayLists. Also, you may need to declare the global ArrayLists as **final** since Java might treat your `new BroadCastReceiver` as an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thx for your info. I updated it, the listview shows the data, but all the data are the same. for eg, the gps got 3 different data. but when click the button turning to the listview page, the 3 data became the same equals to the last time data. Is it sth wrong in the list activity?

Comment: Mind elaborating? Everything looks fine to me at the moment. What do you mean "last time data"? You mean your list is not refreshing the next time the activity is launched?

Comment: I meant that the data is always the one obtained at last.

Comment: That is most likely because you are overwriting the array list somewhere. Probably in your GPS service. Make sure that you always add to the array list instead of rewriting all data.

Comment: I've found the problem, in the list activity. Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**you can start and bind the service with the activity and get data from the service**

Activity Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Created by dheeraj on 24/3/15.
 */
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler handler;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;
    private int k = -100;

    int status;
    private boolean run = true;

    MyServices myServices;

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            myServices = ((MyServices.MyLocalBinder) binder).getService();
            Log.i("", "");

            Thread thread =new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (run) {
                        try {
                            k = myServices.getData();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("", "", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(k));

                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("", "", e);
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("", "", e);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                   Log.e("","");
                }
            });
            thread.setName("Activity Thread");
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i("", "");
            run = false;
        }
    };


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServices.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, 0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Service Code

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by dheeraj on 24/3/15.
 */
public class MyServices extends Service {

    private int data = 0;
    private MyRunnable myRunnable;

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        private boolean run = true;

        public void setRun(){
            run = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(run){
                if(data > 100){
                    stopSelf();
                    return;
                }
                data = data + 5;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private final IBinder myBinder = new MyLocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myBinder;
    }



    public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyServices getService() {
            return MyServices.this;
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread thread =new Thread(myRunnable);
        thread.setName("Service Thread");
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if(myRunnable != null){
            myRunnable.setRun();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    }
```